# Getting a type error with a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I am working on a simple program and I am having this problem with my nested dictionary values returning an integer and getting a `KeyError`.

I have tried initializing the key as a dictionary but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
people = {
    1: {
        'name': 'John',
        'age': '27',
        'sex': 'Male'
    },
    2: {
       'name': 'Marie', 
       'age': '22', 
       'sex': 'Female'
    }
}

todays_names = {}

x=1

for item in people:
    home = people[x]['name']
    todays_names[x] = {}
    todays_names[x]['home'] = home
    x += 1

print(todays_names)

for item in todays_names:
    print(item['home'])
```

I would expect it to print John and Marie for each item but it does not. when i print the dictionary it looks like:

```
 {1: {'home': 'John'}, 2: {'home': 'Marie'}}
```

though which seems valid to me.

Comment: A for loop through a dictionary will return the keys by default (so in the case of `people`, `1` and `2`). You want to use `for item in `todays_names.values()` instead if you want those. Or to get both: `for key, value in some_dict.items()`

Comment: When you are using ordered numbers as keys in a dictionary, that's a flag that using a `list` might just be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are not properly accessing the nested dictionary. This line:

```
for item in todays_names:
    print(item['home'])
```

is throwing an error because item is the key of the outer dictionary while home is the key of the nested dictionary. Your print statement looks something like this:

```
# item = 1
print(1['home'])
```

which is throwing an error. Try something like this:

```
for item in todays_names:
    print(todays_items[item]['home'])
```

This should give you the expected output because `todays_items` is the dictionary, `item` is the key of the outer level and `home` is the key of the nested dictionary. This will print `John` and `Marie`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I am fairly new to python so i missed that syntax.